# is there any way of returning a 0 or 1(boolean) on the basis of a value of a time series metric in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, promql

is there any way to return a boolean value when a time series that has a threshold of 2s is crossed, The metric is usually 0, but if a threshold of 2 is crossed, the return should be a 1?

Comment: Can you add some context?

Comment: @Minsky I have a time series returning a value of either 0 or a whole number( think seconds, Like a response time), i would like to make a query that returns a 1 if the metric returns a value more than 2s , or a 0 otherwise

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the [comparison operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators) in PromQL?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [bool modifier together with comparison operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators). For example, the following query returns 0 when `m` is less than 2, while returning 1 when `m` equals or greater than 2:

```
m >=bool 2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(0 * (sum by (instance) (up) > 1) + 1) or (0 * (sum by (instance) (up) <= 1))
```